# Given a criterion in one vector and a value in 2nd vector, find the closest value in 3rd vector but report the corresponding value in 4th vector

Tags: indexing, match, lookup, sapply, closest

I've got two dataframes.

```
dfx <- data.frame(ID=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
                 a=c( 0.1, 2.1, 1.5, 1.8, 8, 1, 1.4, 39, 100))

  ID     a
1  A   0.1
2  A   2.1
3  A   1.5
4  B   1.8
5  B   8.0
6  B   1.0
7  B   1.4
8  B  39.0
9  B 100.0

dfy<-data.frame(ID=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"),
                aa=c(0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80),
                bb=c(1, -1, 20, -5, 10, 20, 40, 80))

  ID   aa bb
1  A  0.5  1
2  A  1.0 -1
3  A  2.0 20
4  B  5.0 -5
5  B 10.0 10
6  C 20.0 20
7  C 40.0 40
8  D 80.0 80
```

I'm looking for a way to create a new variable in dfx, using the ID and the value in "a" in each row to find the ID-specific "bb", using the nearest value in "aa" relative to "a".  For instance,
for the first row, the returned answer would be 1 (the closest "A" value within "aa" to a = 0.1 is 0.5, which corresponds to bb = 1). The answer for the second row would be 20.

I have seen many examples with sapply and which.min, but I haven't been able to find anything that helps me with this kind of problem. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution**

```
library(data.table)

dtx<-as.data.table(dfx)
dty<-as.data.table(dfy)
setkeyv(dtx,c("ID","a"))
setkeyv(dty,c("ID","aa"))
dtx$ID<-as.character(dtx$ID)
dtx$a<-as.double(dtx$a)
dty$ID<-as.character(dty$ID)
dty$aa<-as.double(dty$aa)
newtable<-dty[dtx,on=c(ID="ID",aa="a"),roll="nearest"]
names(newtable)[names(newtable)=="aa"]<-"a"

  ID     a bb
1:  A   0.1  1
2:  A   1.5 -1
3:  A   2.1 20
4:  B   1.0 -5
5:  B   1.4 -5
6:  B   1.8 -5
7:  B   8.0 10
8:  B  39.0 10
9:  B 100.0 10
```